# Handle inconsistent line endings

Tags: c#, sql-server

sometimes when I open some file, the Visual Studio shows me a dialog about inconsistent line endings but Visual Studio is able to normalize the line endings. 
How can I normalize the line endings (Windows CR LF) in the file by myself with using C#?

I read a definition of stored procedure from SQL Server and save it to the file.

```
File.WriteAllText("procedure.sql", "content");
```

But when I open the file in Visual Studio it gives a warning about inconsistent line endings. SQL Server Management Studio also shows the same warnings when I want to modify the stored procedure.

Comment: Maybe write some code to do it?

Comment: Read the file using a StreamReader and write it back. What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I found the similar question but it didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to normalize to `\r\n` then this should be enough:

```
string filename = "somefile.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
File.WriteAllLines(filename, lines);
```

(it works because the `ReadAllLines` accept both `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`, and then on write `WriteAllLines` always uses `\r\n`).

Note that this won't preserve encoding (for example the presence/absence of the initial BOF for UTF8, or if the file is in Unicode). The file will be written in UTF8 without BOM.